# Excel VBA Formula Format Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a particulary awful time understanding what goes wrong here.

I would like to enter the following formula via VBA:

```
Range("C8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MODE.SNGL('Data'!D:D)"
```

Now, the problem is that VBA instead outputs it as:

```
=MODE.SNGL('Data'!D(D)
```

I tried using chr(58) and also using ' to escape, but no cherry.
Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what code did you use?

Comment: made an edit to show more of the code.

Comment: Others have answered but not that you could use just `ActiveCell.Formula = "=MODE.SNGL(Data!D:D)"`, the pair of `'` are redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use FOrmulaR1C1 you have to pass an R1C1 style reference not A1 style. replace that code by

```
Range("C8").Formula = "=MODE.SNGL('Data'!D:D)"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=MODE.SNGL('Data'!D:D)"
```

Or if you need to use `.FormulaR1C1` property you could do it this way:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MODE.SNGL('Data'!C4:C4)"
```

Comment: fyi since the activecell was in column c the r1c1 version ought to refer to `'Data'!C[1]:C[1]` or `Data!C4:C4` for absolute references

Comment: @JosieP, you right, I improved answer accordingly, thank you!